# How to display an image in the options of select box in CHROME?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<select>    
   <option>image1 text</option>
   <option>image2 text</option>
   <option>image3 text</option>
   <option>image4 text</option>
 </select>
```

How to display an image in the option tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because webkit browsers do not support styling of `<option>` tags.

The most widely used cross browser solution is to use `<ul>` / `<li>`.

You can also refer [this](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/form/form4.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with HTML and CSS only, at least not in Chrome.

But you could try some Javascript magic, e.g. [this](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)

**Edit:** It is possible in Firefox with CSS' property `background-image`, but it doesn't seem to work in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.It is working. Please put your images on div.

HTML Code:

```
 <select id="selected">
 <option value="0">Select</option>
 <option value="a">Images text1</option>
 <option value="b">Images text2</option>
 <option value="c">Images text3</option>
 <option value="d">Images text4</option>
 </select>

<div id="colors">
   <div id="a">
    <img src="http://www.acura.com/images/HomepageSlideshow/home_bg_mdx.jpg" height="200px" width="400px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="b">
    <img src="http://www.acura.com/images/HomepageSlideshow/home_bg_tlx.jpg" height="200px" width="400px" />
    </div>
    <div id="c">
    <img src="http://www.acura.com/images/HomepageSlideshow/home_bg_rlx.jpg" height="200px" width="400px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="d">
    <img src="http://www.acura.com/images/HomepageSlideshow/home_bg_ilx.jpg" height="200px" width="400px"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
    #a
    {
        background-color: red;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    #b
    {
        background-color: green;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
    }
   #c
    {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
    }
   #d
    {
        background-color: darkviolet;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
    }
     #colors div
    {
        display: none;
    }
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#selected").change(function(){
            $('#colors div').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/9p54F/9/)